# number of MIME parts in the MTOM message exceeded the current quota '1000'

Tags: c#

I get this error message:
The number of MIME parts in the MTOM message exceeded the current quota '1000'. To increase the quota, change the 'microsoft:xmldictionaryreader:maxmimeparts' setting in the AppSettings section of the configuration file.

I have added an app.config file to my application and added AppSettings section and 
but it does not work.

this is my code:

```
public static T DeserializeFromMtomStream<T>(io.Stream stream)
    {

        XmlDictionaryReader TR = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateMtomReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);

        DataContractSerializer DCS = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

        return (T)DCS.ReadObject(TR);
    }
```

any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: in appsettings section, i have add this item:

Comment: <add key="microsoft:xmldictionaryreader:maxmimeparts" value="10000"/>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding additional information to your question please edit the question rather than add comments. See the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

in the machine.config file after the configsection add the following:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="microsoft:xmldictionaryreader:maxmimeparts" value="10000"/>
  </appSettings>
```

edit the "value" attribute as you like.

Comment: What is maximum value we can set for 'microsoft:xmldictionaryreader:maxmimeparts' ?

Answer (score 0):

adding the same line `<add key="microsoft:xmldictionaryreader:maxmimeparts" value="10000"/>` to app.config under `<appSettings>` also works